# @NaverNews.Default NameError: name 'NaverNews' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, decorator, nameerror

I found some features if I execute these files in Python IDLE, it works, but if I execute these files in PyCharm, It doesn't work. I want to know the reason why it doesn't work.

```
import os
import sys
file_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.append(file_dir)
sys.path.append('/NaverNews/Main/News/FirstNews')
sys.path.append('/NaverNews/Default/Default')

from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

from FirstNews import *
from Default import *

import datetime
import random

random.seed(datetime.datetime.now())


class NaverNews:
    def __init__(self, NewsLists):
        self.FirstNewsSite = NewsLists
        # self.SecondNewsSite = NewsLists
        # self.ThirdNewsSite = NewsLists
        # self.FourthNewsSite = NewsLists
        # self.FifthNewsSite = NewsLists
        # self.RealTimeNews = NewsLists
        self.Default = NewsLists

    # @property
    # def NewsLists(self):
    #     return self.NewsLists

    # def SelectNums(self, new_NewsLists):
    def __call__(self):
        print("Please Select the News Site")
        MenuInput = input("Select The Menu")
        MenuList = []
        while 1:
            if MenuInput is 1:
                self.FirstNewsSite()
                MenuList.append(FirstNews)

            else:
                self.Default()
                MenuList.append(DefaultNews)
```

And

```
# Default.py
import sys
sys.path.append('/NaverNews/Main/Main')
from Main import *
@NaverNews
def DefaultNews():
    print("Shutting Down the Program")
    exit(0)
DefaultNews()
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python_Class/Web_Crawling_and_ChatBot_1/NaverNews/Main/Main.py", line 12, in 
    from FirstNews import *
  File "E:\Python_Class\Web_Crawling_and_ChatBot_1\NaverNews\Main\News\FirstNews.py", line 3, in 
    from Main import *
  File "E:\Python_Class\Web_Crawling_and_ChatBot_1\NaverNews\Main\Main.py", line 13, in 
    from Default import *
  File "E:\Python_Class\Web_Crawling_and_ChatBot_1\NaverNews\Default\Default.py", line 6, in 
    @NaverNews.Default
NameError: name 'NaverNews' is not defined

Comment: You haven't posted the code where the error occurs.

Comment: Umm.. Actually, I didn't know how to post the code, So I take around 1 hour

Comment: Is the first file `Main.py`? If so, you have a circular import.

Comment: But if I get rid of the lines that I Imported, the file (Main.py) cannot recognize other File (First File)

Comment: I understand that, and there are ways to resolve circular imports. I suggest you to do a little research.